# What does "la fois" mean in "prend forme à la fois dans..."

Tags: vocabulaire

I encountered this text in a Babbel lesson:

... Un véritable voyage esthétique, où la poésie prend forme à la fois dans les mots et les images.

I know "prend forme" means "take shape", but what does "à la fois" mean? I know "la fois" means "the time".

I plugged this into Google Translate and it wasn't clear from its translation either.

Comment: Google Translate gives *both* which is fine. *À la fois* is close to "at the same time".

Comment: Google translate is not a translator. I would not suggest it. The Larousse French>English is a real dictionary. It means: both in words and in images.

Comment: @Lambie Obviously, GT **is** a translator, although belonging to the computer programs type and currently not the best one available. In that case, its translation wasn't bad.

Comment: We would never say at the same time here. We would say both here. "where poetry takes the form of **both words and images** . https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/fois/34330#655006 I  have no idea why your comment was upvoted. I guess people just do not know the difference between google translate and Larousse. What can I say?

Comment: I looked it up in Larousse (I should've tried that first...) and under expressions it actually says "À la fois, tout à la fois ... [means] en même temps"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selon [L'Académie française](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-fois-la-fois-la-fois-mais-aussi) :

> La locution adverbiale à la fois signifie « en même temps, simultanément ».